# Заполнение Listview из HashMap + JSON

Tags: android, парсер, json, синтаксический-анализ

Есть код:

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
                String key1 = json.getString("key1");
                String key2 = json.getString("key2");
                String key3 = json.getString("key3");
                String key4 = json.getString("key4");
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> neww = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Iterator itr = json.keys();

                    String key = itr.next().toString();
                    neww.put(key, json.get(key).toString());

                    keyList.add(neww);
                }
                }

                return true;
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Он выводит только одно значение "value4" во всех 4 строках списка, а должен "value4","value3","value2","value1". Не пойму, в чем дело! Кому несложно, намекните или подскажите.

Список заполняю через SimpleAdaptor вот так:

```
       ListAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, keyList,
                R.layout.items, new String[]{KEY4, KEY3,KEY2,KEY1 },
                new int[]{R.id.key4});

       setListAdapter(adapter);

class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource,
                           String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }
}
```

JSON беру [тут](http://echo.jsontest.com/key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3/key4/value4/).

Прошу строго не судить - только учусь.
За помощь заранее спасибо всем. =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Надо не так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
   HashMap<String, String> neww = new HashMap<String, String>();
   ...
}
```

А так (объявить хеш-таблицу вне цикла):

```
HashMap<String, String> neww = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

   ...
}
```

Comment: ничего не поменялось ...

Comment: мне кажеться, что дело в адаптере.

Comment: @Alerx покажите код адаптера тогда )

Comment: в коде, в самом низу

Comment: @Alerx я вижу создание экземпляра MySimpleAdapter, но не вижу кода MySimpleAdapter.

Comment: сорри .. добавил

Answer (score 1):

Выше дан правильный ответ. У вас HashMap инициализируется каждый раз внутри цикла, поэтому на выходе из цикла в нем останется только последнее значение. Все закономерно.

И еще, в adapter вы передаете 4 параметра from и только 1 to. Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
   ListAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, keyList,
            R.layout.items, new String[]{KEY4, KEY3,KEY2,KEY1 },
            new int[]{R.id.key4, R.id.key3, R.id.key2, R.id.key1});
```